# Cannot invoke disableStyle() on the array type PShape[]

Tags: processing

I got a problem with my processing Code.
I made a grid witch is filled with some SVG's at an random position. With PNG's and the PImage it work's fine but I want to do it with SVG to change the Stroke Color, Weight and Size of the Icons.

After I wrote the Code into the Shape to get it work with SVG's I wanted to place an disableStyle() to change the values but I get the error "Cannot invoke disableStyle() on the array type PShape[]".

Anyone a suggestion what the Problem is?

Hope for some good answers. Thank you!

```
int countHorizontal = 12;
int countVertical = 6;
int seed = 0;

PShape[] Icon = new PShape[8];

void setup() {
  size(1600, 800);
  noLoop();
  randomSeed(seed);
  
  Icon[0] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_1.svg"); Icon[1] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_2.svg");
  Icon[2] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_3.svg"); Icon[3] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_4.svg");
  Icon[4] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_5.svg"); Icon[5] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_6.svg");
  Icon[6] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_7.svg"); Icon[7] = loadShape("SVGIcons/Icon_8.svg");
}

void draw() {
  background(#eeeeee);
  
  Icon.disableStyle();
  
  strokeWeight(2);
  color(#000000);

  
  for (int i = 0; i < countHorizontal; i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < countVertical; j = j + 1) {

      float w = float(width) / countHorizontal;
      float h = float(height) / countVertical;
      float x = w * i;
      float y = h * j;

      shape(Icon[(int)random(Icon.length)], x, y, 100, 100); 
    }
  }
}

void keyReleased() { 
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    seed = seed - 1;
  }

  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    seed = seed + 1;
  }
  
  randomSeed(seed);
  redraw();

  println(seed);

  //saveFrame("export/animation_####.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Icon` variable is of type `PShape[]`. The brackets mean it is an [array](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html) of PShape objects. `Array` does not have a method called `disableStyle()` which is why you get an error that you can’t invoke that method on the `Icon` variable.

To use that method, you’ll need to access the individual PShape elements in the array:

```
Icon[0].disableStyle(); // etc
```

Comment: Thx, it work's perfectly.
Love how StackOverflow works!

Comment: Can I give just one icon a specific width and height? They have all the same sizes except one which is twice the width.